# Using the table, explain what the 95% confidence intervals mean for both age and sex.?

Tags: confidence-interval

[image: Table 1]

I just do not understand the ranges given for the 95% confidence intervals. For age, the range is 0.9 - 1.3. and for sex the range is 1.2-4.0. What does that mean?

Comment: This is not clear. For that purpose, articles usually add a caption with explanations and a statistical methods section. If you could add these, we can try to give you an answer.

Comment: For threads about confidence intervals for the odds ratio, please [see this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=odds+ratio+confidence+interval+regression). Otherwise, are you trying to ask what a confidence interval is or are you asking about what an odds ratio means?